# Collect class hierarchy of Flex application

Tags: apache-flex, reflection, introspection, class-hierarchy

I was wondering: If I have built a Flex application, is it possible to somehow collect it's class hierarchy using reflection or some other method? For example if I have defined components: CustomButton which derives from Button and RedCustomButton which derives from CustomButton. Is it possible to get a result like: "Button <- CustomButton <- RedCustomButton"?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `describeType`

```
trace(describeType(UIComponent));
```

[public function describeType(value:*):XML Reference from Adobe Help](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType%28%29)

> Produces an XML object that describes the ActionScript object named as
>   the parameter of the method. This method implements the programming
>   concept of reflection for the ActionScript language.

Also I recommend you to use [Spicelib Reflect](http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley/docs/3.0/manual/reflection.php#intro) library.